# Docker tool in Jenkins container (with mounted Docker socket) is not finding a Docker daemon to connect to

Tags: linux, bash, sockets, jenkins, docker

I just started a Jenkins docker container with a mounted docker socket like the following:

```
docker run -d \
    --publish 8080:8080 \
    --publish 50000:50000 \
    --volume /my_jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    --name my_jenkins_container \
    company/my_jenkins:latest
```

Then I bash into the container like this:

```
docker exec -it my_jenkins_container bash
```

---

A `tool 'docker'` command in a Jenkins pipeline script has automatically installed a Docker binary at the following path: `/var/jenkins_home/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool/docker/bin/docker`

However, when I try to run Docker commands from that Docker binary (*assuming that it will connect with the Docker socket that has been mounted at `/var/run/docker.sock`*) it returns ***the following error***:

```
$ /var/jenkins_home/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool/docker/bin/docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

---

***How can I ensure that*** this Docker binary (*the binary that has been automatically installed via the Jenkins' `tool 'docker'` command*) runs its Docker commands by connecting to the mounted Docker socket at `/var/run/docker.sock`?

Comment: > How can i ensure < Using `strace`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I must ensure (not just check/verify) that this docker tool can connect with the mounted docker socker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Short Answer:***

The file permissions of the mounted Docker socket file had to be revised.

---

***Long Answer:***

When I simply tried to execute `/path/to/dockerTool/bin/docker ps -a` on the Docker container, it was producing an error.

```
$ docker exec -it my_jenkins_container bash -c "/var/jenkins_home/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool/docker/bin/docker ps -a"
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Then, when I tried to execute `/path/to/dockerTool/bin/docker ps -a` with `user=root`, it worked fine.

```
$ docker exec -it --user=root my_jenkins_container bash -c "/var/jenkins_home/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool/docker/bin/docker ps -a"
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
c9dd56411efe        company/my_jenkins:latest   "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   49 seconds ago      Up 49 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   my_jenkins_container
```

So it means I just needed to ***set the right permissions to the Docker socket***. All I had to do was `chgrp` the socket file to the `jenkins` group so that the `jenkins` group/users can read/write to that socket file (*the before & after of the `chgrp` command is included here*):

```
$ docker exec -it my_jenkins_container bash -c "ls -l /var/run/docker.sock"
srw-rw---- 1 root 999     0 Jan 15 08:29 /var/run/docker.sock

$ docker exec -it --user=root my_jenkins_container bash -c "chgrp jenkins /var/run/docker.sock"

$ docker exec -it my_jenkins_container bash -c "ls -l /var/run/docker.sock"
srw-rw---- 1 root jenkins 0 Jan 15 08:29 /var/run/docker.sock
```

After that, executing `/path/to/dockerTool/bin/docker ps -a` as a non-root user worked fine

```
$ docker exec -it my_jenkins_container bash -c "/var/jenkins_home/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool/docker/bin/docker ps -a"
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
c9dd56411efe        company/my_jenkins:latest   "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   3 minutes ago      Up 3 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   my_jenkins_container
```